# WPF MVVM Database First Create User

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, mvvm

I am currently developing a WPF MVVM application for a school project everything is going well except that I can't figure out how to create a new user and add it to my database.

Here is my model (Generated from my database)

```
public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Recipes = new HashSet<Recipe>();
            ShoppingLists = new HashSet<ShoppingList>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Password { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ShoppingList> ShoppingLists { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my View (All styling were removed for better readability)

```
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Email}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Username}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Password}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding PasswordConfirm}" /> />
            <Button Command="{Binding CreateNewAccountSubmit}" Content="Create Account" />
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
internal class CreateAccountViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string _email;
        public string Email
        {
            get
            {
                return _email;
            }
            set
            {
                _email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Email));
            }
        }
        private string _username;
        public string Username
        {
            get
            {
                return _username;
            }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
            }
        }
        private string _password;
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return _password;
            }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
            }
        }
        private string _passwordConfirm;
        public string PasswordConfirm
        {
            get
            {
                return _passwordConfirm;
            }
            set
            {
                _passwordConfirm = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PasswordConfirm));
            }
        }
        public ICommand CreateNewAccountSubmit { get; }
        public ICommand GoToLoginPage { get; }

        public CreateAccountViewModel(Stores.NavigationStore _navigationStore)
        {
            CreateNewAccountSubmit = new CreateNewAccountSubmitCommand();
            GoToLoginPage = new GoToLoginPageCommand(_navigationStore);
        }
    }
```

Here is my command for the button

```
    internal class CreateNewAccountSubmitCommand : CommandBase
    {
        FoodManagerDbContext dbContext = new FoodManagerDbContext();

        public override void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
          /*Do something here that I don't know maybe with the 
            parameter?
          */
        }
    }
```

So my question here is how would I go about being able to create a new user from the form? Here is what I usually do with LINQ.

```
User u = new User()
{
  Email= txtEmail.Text,
  Username = txtUsername.Text,
  Password = txtPassword.Text,
}

dbContext.User.Add(u);
dbContext.Savechange();
```

But now I can't access the text box directly I have to go through the binding and that where I'm lost.

If you need any more info I will provide it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you inject the command implementation with the view model you could either access itw properties directly or call a method of it that performs the write to the database:

```
internal class CreateNewAccountSubmitCommand : CommandBase
{
    readonly CreateAccountViewModel viewModel;
    FoodManagerDbContext dbContext = new FoodManagerDbContext();

    public CreateNewAccountSubmitCommand(CreateAccountViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public override void Execute(object? _)
    {
        User u = new User()
        {
            Email= viewModel.Email,
            Username = viewModel.Username,
            Password = viewModel.Password,
        }

        dbContext.User.Add(u);
        dbContext.Savechange();
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public CreateAccountViewModel(Stores.NavigationStore _navigationStore)
{
    CreateNewAccountSubmit = new CreateNewAccountSubmitCommand(this);
    GoToLoginPage = new GoToLoginPageCommand(_navigationStore);
}
```

Or move the logic from the command implementation to a method in view model (called `Save` below):

```
internal class CreateNewAccountSubmitCommand : CommandBase
{
    readonly CreateAccountViewModel viewModel;

    public CreateNewAccountSubmitCommand(CreateAccountViewModel viewModel) =>
        this.viewModel = viewModel;

    public override void Execute(object? _) => viewModel.Save();
}
```